# KO IF observable matches value show/hide

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: myObs" />
    var myObs = ko.observable(); 
       <!-- ko if: myObs === "hello" -->
            Whatever! html etc...
        <!-- /ko -->
```

If my observable value equals "hello" then show "whatever!". When a user inputs "hello" I want this field to show and when it gets removed from input it disappears again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add brackets after `myObs`, otherwise you're comparing the observable function to the `"hello"` string and not the value of the observable itself:

```js
var vm = {
  myObs: ko.observable("hello")
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: myObs, valueUpdate: 'input'" />
<!-- ko if: myObs() === "hello" -->
  Whatever! html etc...
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Is there a way not to have the "hello" in the input by default?

Comment: @TomRudge yep, just get rid of the `"hello"` part within the observable: `myObs: ko.observable()`. I only put that there to make it obvious that the HTML `if` condition was working. :)